# How can I retrieve the "Description" field of inspect.exe in my pywinauto based automation script?

Tags: winapi, ui-automation, pywinauto

I have the following SysTreeView32 element from which I would like to retrieve the "Description" field:

[image: The description bield is highlighted]

In my pywinauto script (based on win32 backend), I can retrieve pretty easily the TreeViewWrapper element by looking for the class type and eventually looking at the items text, but some information that I need is only available in the Description field of this element.

I was not able to find a way to retrieve this information.

I tried in UIA mode as well:

[image]

But in this case, it does not even appear in the information.

So I tried using the TreeItemWrapper element with the UIA backend in pywinauto, but I could not find the appropriate description not even in the UIAElementInfo.  Although something looked pretty similar in the following line:

```
impl = uia_defs.get_elem_interface(elem, "LegacyIAccessible").
```

When I call the `legacy_properties` of the `uia_controls.TreeItemWrapper`, I get:

```
{'ChildId': 0,
 'DefaultAction': '',
 'Description': '',
 'Help': '',
 'KeyboardShortcut': '',
 'Name': 'Execute multiple tasks(MultiTask_ImportSysD)',
 'Role': 36,
 'State': 3145730,
 'Value': ''}
```

And in there, the Description is empty.

Comment: Can you re-take the screenshot of `Inspect.exe` in "UI Automation" mode instead of MSAA? Please enable "Show hierarchy" as well.

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested, I have even used the UIA back to access the element, but I am not able to retrieve the description, even using what seemed to me like the IAccessible::getCurrentDescription...  Iam am still  not able to get access to it!

Comment: The windows SDK documentation clearly states that this information is not available through UIA:
    Note  The Description property is often used incorrectly and is not supported 
    by Microsoft UI Automation. Microsoft Active Accessibility server developers             
    should not use this property. If more information is needed for accessibility  
    and automation scenarios, use the properties supported by UI Automation 
    elements and control patterns.

Comment: Did you try method .legacy_properties() in pywinauto? It returns a dict of MSAA properties. Don’t recall if “Description” is there.

Comment: Yes description is in there, I have copied the results.  But legacy_properties is only available in UIA.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that property comes from [`IAccessible::get_accDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleacc/nf-oleacc-iaccessible-get_accdescription).

MSDN says that property is deprecated but if you still want to use it, call `AccessibleObjectFromWindow` to get a `IAccessible` for a window.

Comment: I was looking for this actually, but I was hoping that there would be some helpers in pywinauto to get this directly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could not find this possibility through the pywinauto exposed API.

Although pywniauto does expose the Description property through the `legacy_properties` of the `uia_controls.TreeItemWrapper` instance, but it returns an empty string.  This correlates with the note in teh Windows SDK documentation that states:

> Note  The Description property is often used incorrectly and is not supported by Microsoft UI Automation. Microsoft Active Accessibility server developers should not use this property. If more information is needed for accessibility and automation scenarios, use the properties supported by UI Automation elements and control patterns.

In the end, I finally developed a small piece of code to search for the element that I need the description of and I could retrieve the Description from there.  Here is the code:

```
# for OleAcc access
import ctypes
import comtypes, comtypes.automation, comtypes.client

comtypes.client.GetModule('oleacc.dll')

def accDescription(iaccessible, cid):
    objChildId = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    objChildId.vt = comtypes.automation.VT_I4
    objChildId.value = cid
    objDescription = comtypes.automation.BSTR()
    iaccessible._IAccessible__com__get_accDescription(objChildId, ctypes.byref(objDescription))
    return objDescription.value

def accRole(iaccessible, cid):
    objChildId = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    objChildId.vt = comtypes.automation.VT_I4
    objChildId.value = cid
    objRole = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    objRole.vt = comtypes.automation.VT_BSTR
    iaccessible._IAccessible__com__get_accRole(objChildId, objRole)
    return AccRoleNameMap[objRole.value]

def accState(iaccessible, cid):
    '''Get Element State'''
    objChildId = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    objChildId.vt = comtypes.automation.VT_I4
    objChildId.value = cid
    objState = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    iaccessible._IAccessible__com__get_accState(objChildId, ctypes.byref(objState))
    return objState.value

def accName(iaccessible, cid):
    '''Get Element Name'''
    objChildId = comtypes.automation.VARIANT()
    objChildId.vt = comtypes.automation.VT_I4
    objChildId.value = cid
    objName = comtypes.automation.BSTR()
    iaccessible._IAccessible__com__get_accName(objChildId, ctypes.byref(objName))
    return objName.value

def accDescendants(iaccessible):
    """Iterate all desencendants of an object iaccessible, including the current one.

    Arguments:
    iaccessible -- the IAccessible element to start from

    Yields:
    (IAcessible instance, Child id)
    """
    yield (iaccessible, 0)
    objAccChildArray = (comtypes.automation.VARIANT * iaccessible.accChildCount)()
    objAccChildCount = ctypes.c_long()
    ctypes.oledll.oleacc.AccessibleChildren(iaccessible, 0, iaccessible.accChildCount, objAccChildArray, ctypes.byref(objAccChildCount))
    for i in range(objAccChildCount.value):
        objAccChild = objAccChildArray[i]
        if objAccChild.vt == comtypes.automation.VT_DISPATCH:
            # query the sub element accessible interface
            newiaccessible = objAccChild.value.QueryInterface(comtypes.gen.Accessibility.IAccessible)
            # then loop over its descendants
            for (__i, __c) in accDescendants(newiaccessible):
                yield (__i, __c)
        else: #if objAccChild.vt == comtypes.automation.VT_I4:
            yield (iaccessible, objAccChild.value)


def findObjIAccessible(handle, text):
    """Find the IAccessible based on the name, starting from a specific window handle

    Arguments:
    handle -- the window handle from which to search for the element
    text -- text that should be contained in the name of the IAccessible instance

    Return:
    (None, 0) if not found
    (IAccessible instance, child id) of the first element whose name contains the text
    """
    iacc = ctypes.POINTER(comtypes.gen.Accessibility.IAccessible)()

    ctypes.oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(handle, 0, ctypes.byref(comtypes.gen.Accessibility.IAccessible._iid_), ctypes.byref(iacc))

    for (ia, ch) in accDescendants(iacc):
        n = accName(ia, ch)
        if n != None and text in n:
            return (ia, ch)
    else:
        return (None, 0)
```